# Fixing Chrome incompatibility with BFLLR Dynamic Library

Tags: google-chrome, dll

Recently after updating Chrome I noticed that the menu icon turned orange, and at the top of the menu list it says "Software Incompatibility: Learn More". This option takes me to a page that lists a bunch of .dll files that Chrome uses.

At the top of the list is "BFLLR Dynamic Library" (%systemroot%\system32\bfllr.dll), a bit of searching and it looks like this is a DLL made by Bigfoot Networks, Inc. which is the company that makes Killer gaming network cards (which my system has).

Obviously if this DLL has something to do with my network card then it's pretty important if I want to browse the web, but Chrome doesn't like it.

So two questions: Why is there a problem with this DLL (or more specifically, what is the problem), and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your systems manufacturers website for driver updates, a newer version may be available that no longer conflicts with Chrome.